# Verificar palavra codificada java/Jogo da forca

Tags: java

Boa noite, sou novo aqui no fórum e também em programação, estou vendo java no momento, tenho um trabalho que consiste em um jogo da forca em java, a parte da classe ja fiz(espero que esteja certo). Estou com dificuldade em verificar se a letra foi digitada, se ela pertence a palavra.

```
package classes;

import java.util.Random;

public class Palavras {

    private String[] palavras = {"cachorro", "baleia", "arara", "chevrolet", "volksvagen", "samsung", "colher", "tablet", "espanha", "senegal"};
    private String palavra;
    private String letra;
    private Random palavraSorteada = new Random();


    public Palavras() {
        palavra = palavras[palavraSorteada.nextInt(palavras.length)];
    }

    public String getPalavra() {
        return palavra;
    }

    public void setPalavra(String palavra) {
        this.palavra = palavra;
    }

    public String getLetra() {
        return letra;
    }

    public void setLetra(String letra) {
        this.letra = letra;
    }

    public char[] codificarPalavra() {
        char[] traco = new char[palavra.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < palavra.length(); i++) {
            traco[i] ='_';

        }
        return traco;

    }

    public String dica() {
        String dica="";
        if (palavra.equals(palavras[0]) || palavra.equals(palavras[1]) || palavra.equals(palavras[2])) { //etc
            dica = "Animal";
        }
        if(palavra.equals(palavras[3]) || palavra.equals(palavras[4]) || palavra.equals(palavras[5])){
            dica = "Marca";
        }
        if(palavra.equals(palavras[6])){
            dica = "cozinha";
        }
        if(palavra.equals(palavras[7])){
            dica = "eletrônico";
        }
        if(palavra.equals(palavras[8]) || palavra.equals(palavras[9])){
            dica = "país";
        }

        return dica;
    }

    public boolean verifica(char letra) {
        // char[] l = letra.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < palavra.length(); i++) {
            if (palavra.charAt(i) == letra) {
                //palavra[i] = letra; vc só quer verificar se existe.
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

a questão é tentei fazer de dois jeitos funcionar e não obtive sucesso.

a primeira foi com botões
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e a outra é digito a letra num TextField e verifico com a palavra, mas dos dois jeito não consegui.

A dificuldade é na parte lógica da execução do programa.

Comment: Tá, mas aí a sua dúvida está muito ampla. Qual é o problema realmente? Não consegui fazer funcionar não é um problema propriamente dito e é muito indefinido.

Comment: Então, não estou conseguindo fazer com que a letra digitada, seja conferida com a palavra que tenho que adivinhar. Tipo se for um TextField, pegar a letra que digitei apertar o botao verificar, se estiver certa coloca a letra na posição correta, se não erro+1.

Comment: Nesse caso não tem muito como ajudar, sua dúvida é muito ampla e não temos o código completo para auxiliar